# WebSocket using sockjs-client and stompjs cannot connect if I do not connect immediately after client creation

Tags: javascript, websocket, sockjs

I was trying to connect to the remote only one time when the page loaded and subscribe channels afterwards when necessary.

To ensure the code can be shared by different pages, I wrote the code (closure) as follows and export the function `webSocket` as this:

```
export function webSocket() {
  const socket = new SockJS(WebSocketEndPoint.RESOURCE_CONTROLLER);
  const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  let isConnected = false;
  function subscribe(address, callback) {
    if (isConnected) {
      stompClient.subscribe(address, callback);
    } else {
      stompClient.connect({}, () => {
        isConnected = true;
        stompClient.subscribe(address, callback);
      });
    }
  };
  function subscribeRealtimeExecOutput(addr, callback){ 
      subscribe(addr, callback);
  }

  return {
    subscribeRealtimeExecOutput,
  };
}
```

And

Use it in other pages as follows:

```
import { webSocket } from '../../websocket/websocketService';

//in the constructor
this.subscriber = webSocket().subscribeRealtimeExecOutput;

//used when required
this.subscriber(pane.jobIdentifier, (data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And I hope the `connect` method will only be run once within the same page and the subscriber will then subscribe different channels based on the connection.

But, it seems it won't work - the connection will not be set up and consequently the browser just prompt me about **Opening Web Socket...**

Anyone can help? Thank you so much for your help.

Sincerely, Hearen

Comment: I found something funny related to this problem: `Once a STOMP client is created, it must call its connect() method to effectively connect and authenticate to the STOMP server. `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After testing locally myself, I found out that after I create the *client* and directly **connect** to the server, everything just works like a charm. So I refactored my code **subscribe** as follows:

```
function subscribe(address, callback) {
    if (isConnected) {
      stompClient.subscribe(address, callback);
    } else {
      stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
      isConnected = true;
      stompClient.connect({}, () => {
        stompClient.subscribe(address, callback);
      }, () => {
        console.error('Sorry, I cannot connect to the server right now.');
      });
    }
  }
```

In which if the connection is still not set up, I create the **client** again and directory set the **isConnected** and connect to the server.

Later on, I am just too curious about what's going on and sought something interesting on this:

http://jmesnil.net/stomp-websocket/doc/

> Once a STOMP client is created, it must call its connect() method to effectively connect and authenticate to the STOMP server.

Besides

> But what happens if the connection fails? the connect() method accepts an optional error_callbackargument which will be called if the client is not able to connect to the server.

And a post from [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361917/automatic-reconnect-with-stomp-js-in-node-js-application/22403521#22403521), which further confirm my refactor

> I create a new instance of Stomp.Client since the current one has its Web Socket closed and there is no way to reopen a Web Socket once it it closed.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add an important piece of information to this post. I had the same problem described in the original question, but the `stompclient.connect();` function got called directly after i declared/initialized the websocket in my javascript.

My faulty code looked like this:

```
var socket = new SockJS('/game-websocket');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

window.onload = function (){
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {

        ...

    }
}
```

The error i encountered got caused by separating the declaration/initialization from the connection with the line `window.onload = function (){}`. Apparently the time it takes for the window to load is corrupting the following websocket connection in some way. (but not consistently, what made it kinda difficult to find the error in the first place)

In my case this separation wasn't really needed and my fixed code looked like this:

```
window.onload = function (){

    var socket = new SockJS('/game-websocket');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);

    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {

        ...

    }
}
```